# Emacs load-path scala-mode

Tags: scala, emacs

I am trying to install ENSIME for emacs. On the first step, when I integrate the `./misc/scala-tool-support/emacs` .elc files, the instructions say to

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/some/directory/scala-mode")
```

Because of the way the directory is structured (where there is no dir `scala-mode` but all of the .el files are called `scala-mode`), I am unsure what this exactly specifies. I originally thought it jsut meant to do something like:

`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/...../misc/scala-tool-support/emacs/")`, but reading further down to the following made me rethink my assumption.

```
(setq yas/my-directory "/path/to/some/directory/scala-mode/contrib/yasnippet/snippets")
(yas/load-directory yas/my-directory)
```

Can someone clarify this please?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

The `yas/load-directory` call has nothing to do with your `load-path`. Yes, you had it right originally. Is this not working? If so, what error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my setup for scala-mode and ensime on Emacs.  I'm on OS X.
In the vendor/scala directory, it's just all the .el files from the compiler distribution.
And ensime/dist is bin/ elisp/ and lib/ directories from a github download.

```
    ;; Scala Mode
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/you/.emacs.d/vendor/scala")


(require 'scala-mode-auto)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.scala$" . scala-mode))
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/ensime/dist")
(require 'ensime)
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook 'ensime-scala-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this and then tried doing somehting like M-x eval-buffer. I got "Cannot open load file: ensime". I also tried just loading a .scala file and using M-x ensime. That returned [No match]. Thoughts?

Comment: It's not loading ensime then.  What's in your ensime dist directory?

Comment: @user592419: I also installed `scala-mode` and `ensime` today. I'm on Linux, but my emacs' configuration is identical to tylerweir's (except the scala-mode and ensime locations that are in my case `/usr/local/typesafe-stack/misc/scala-tool-support/emacs` and `/usr/local/ensime/elisp`).

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the [scala-tool-support repo](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/16697/scala-tool-support/trunk/src/emacs), all of the scala-related snippets for had been [included in Yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsnippets%2Fscala-mode) now. If we use the Yasnippet release version newer than 0.5.7 , the snippets for scala-mode should be included in /path/to/yasnippet/text-mode/scala-mode, so we don't need to set `yas/load-directory` by ourselves.